# connect redis (redislab) with node (typescript) using handy-redis

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis

I'm trying to connect Redis (redislab) with Node application using handy-redis npm.

```
import { createNodeRedisClient } from 'handy-redis';

(async function() {
    
    const client = createNodeRedisClient({
        host: 'redis-<link>.ap-south-1-1.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com',
        port: <port>,
        password: <password>,
    });

})();
```

But Typescript returning this error:

```
Argument of type '{ host: string; port: string; password: string; }' is not  
assignable to parameter of type 'RedisClient'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'host' does not exist in type
'RedisClient'
```

Though Typescript returning error, but the app properly working. 
I've tried for long time to solve this, but couldn't success. 
Please any one suggest me, how to properly use handy-redis with redislab to get rid of from this error.